# How to delete all but the oldest duplicate flle listed in a text file using rm

Tags: bash, macos, rm

I have followed an article by [Rick James](https://www.rickmakes.com/find-duplicate-files-using-the-command-line-on-a-mac-or-linux/?unapproved=2583&moderation-hash=df974469691817e315b6ec2dee8bedaf#comment-2583) on how to locate duplicates. He never went farther than producing a list of files that contain their md5 hash, count, file name.

```
find . -type f -not -empty -exec md5 -r {} \; > ~/Desktop/file_list.txt

sort ~/Desktop/file_list.txt > ~/Desktop/file_list_sort.txt

cat ~/Desktop/file_list_sort.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -v '^   1 ' | awk '{ t=$1 ; $1=$2; $2=t; print }' | sort > ~/Desktop/file_counts.txt

join -1 1 -2 1 ~/Desktop/file_counts.txt ~/Desktop/file_list_sort.txt |sort -k2,2 -n -k1,1 > ~/Desktop/file-dups.txt
```

I have ended up with a list that only contains files that have more than one copy in a particular directory.

Instead of going through manually I am looking for a way to `rm` all but the oldest one of each duplicated file.

Example of file containing the md5 hash, the count of duplicates, and the file name.

```
0b54612fad50cf28605bdb1d57eb36bf 3 ./20180505 142648-0586AA69.m4a
0b54612fad50cf28605bdb1d57eb36bf 3 ./20180505 142648-39FD9F97.m4a
0b54612fad50cf28605bdb1d57eb36bf 3 ./20180505 142648-B8DCAD18.m4a
0ecba4fdcaeacfe6f48639a6a3caeef6 3 ./20180526 202610-67CA5ED6.m4a
0ecba4fdcaeacfe6f48639a6a3caeef6 3 ./20180526 202610-9210FBD9.m4a
0ecba4fdcaeacfe6f48639a6a3caeef6 3 ./20180526 202610-9E04AD1E.m4a
a44705a9a57c1cd641148824cd7dd16f 3 ./20180613 133550-1DF6AAF3.m4a
a44705a9a57c1cd641148824cd7dd16f 3 ./20180613 133550-728FE95E.m4a
a44705a9a57c1cd641148824cd7dd16f 3 ./20180613 133550-A15C8237.m4a
```

Things to consider:

1. I would like to end up with the oldest of each group of duplicates but in this case two of the three share the same creation date.
2. This list would may contain 2 or more duplicates of each file. In this case there were 3.

Desired outcome:
If there are two duplicates I want to delete all but the oldest one.
If there are three duplicates I want to delete all but the oldest one. If there are four duplicates I want to delete all but the oldest one. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes).

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it won't necessarily save the oldest:

```
find . -type f -not -empty -exec md5 -r  {} \; | sort | while read cksum fname; do [[ "$lastcksum" = "$cksum" ]] && rm $fname; lastcksum=$cksum;  done
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short bash script, lets call it "dup.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 5<$1
last_hashkey=""
last_file=""
while true ; do
        read line<&5
        if [ "$line" == "" ] ; then break ; fi
        current_hashkey=${line%% *}
        current_file=${line##* }
        echo "current_hashkey=$current_hashkey ; current_file=$current_file"
        if [ "$current_hashkey" == "$last_hashkey" ] ; then
                rm $last_file
        fi
        last_hashkey=$current_hashkey
        last_file=$current_file
done
exec 5<&-
```

The script does the following:
(1) it opens the file in its command line argument,
(2) loops for reading every line of the file (separating the md5sum and the filename)
(3) keeps the the values of both the current line and the previous line (keeping the md5 and the filenames)
(4) when two successive lines of the file have the same md5, it removes the former filename.

At the end of the script, only remains the file in the latest line with any given md5 sum value.

Let's assume your list of md5sum and filenames are in a file named "list.txt" containing:

```
0b54612fad50cf28605bdb1d57eb36bf 3 ./20180505 142648-0586AA69.m4a
0b54612fad50cf28605bdb1d57eb36bf 3 ./20180505 142648-39FD9F97.m4a
0b54612fad50cf28605bdb1d57eb36bf 3 ./20180505 142648-B8DCAD18.m4a
0ecba4fdcaeacfe6f48639a6a3caeef6 3 ./20180526 202610-67CA5ED6.m4a
0ecba4fdcaeacfe6f48639a6a3caeef6 3 ./20180526 202610-9210FBD9.m4a
0ecba4fdcaeacfe6f48639a6a3caeef6 3 ./20180526 202610-9E04AD1E.m4a
a44705a9a57c1cd641148824cd7dd16f 3 ./20180613 133550-1DF6AAF3.m4a
a44705a9a57c1cd641148824cd7dd16f 3 ./20180613 133550-728FE95E.m4a
a44705a9a57c1cd641148824cd7dd16f 3 ./20180613 133550-A15C8237.m4a
```

Now, if you type the following command:

```
bash dup.sh list.txt
```

You're ony going to keep the one file corresponding to the latest line of any given md5sum value, removing the former files with the same md5sum value...